# How to route FlutterTTS speech to a phone call initiated by flutter_phone_direct_caller plugin?

Tags: flutter, call, text-to-speech, voice

Does anyone know how to route speech/voice that is generated FlutterTts.speak to a voice call initiated by flutter_phone_direct_caller plugin?

I am initiating a voice call using FlutterPhoneDirectCaller and then using FlutterTts.speak() to play an automated text message, a voice call is getting through but the message played by FlutterTts.speak() is heard properly on the caller side but can't be heard on the callee side.

I want to make a direct phone call from my app to a given number and play a message.

Thanking you in anticipation!